# How can i use loads or JS functional programming approach to retrieve attributes from nested data structures?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, lodash, immutable.js

[image]

My goal is to get the attributes from the object, attributes like: 
**Color, Icon, Name**.

(*for now lets call **project** to the object*)

The tricky part is that i need to get all the attributes from all the **projects** where the user is in.

Comment: You're looking for `_.filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the issue using filter, map and includes, i forgot to mention that im using immutable data structures.

something like this:

`const memberProjects = projects.filter(project => project.get('Members').map(member => member.get('MemberId')).includes(memberId));`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var projects = [/* Your big array */];

var userID = 1223456;
var userProjects = [];
for(project in projects) {
    for (member in project) {
    if(member.MemberId == userID) {
        userProjects.push(project);
    }
  }
}
```

There might be a more optimized solution though.